# How to interprocess communication and scheduling algorithms interact?

Tags: operating-systems

I was listening back to a lecture I had, hinting on what we should revise for our upcoming exam. Since then I've covered all the parts, but having difficult in decrypting the following

> You might want to look at the interaction between scheduling algorithms and interprocess communication.

I understand both interprocess communication and scheduling algorithms but don't have an opinion/nor can find one on the link between the two. If anyone could inform me I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Such interaction arises when a high-priority task needs to communicate in some way with a low-priority task. Scheduling algorithms may need to take into account such communication. For example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion .